# Консоль выводит вопросительные знаки вместо нужных специальных знаков

Tags: c#

В консоль нужно вывести изображение, содержащие такие знаки(`⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⣤⡤⠞⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠓⢤⣀⠀⠀⠀⠱⣄⠳⢤⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀`)
Проблема заключается в том, что на винде выводит вопросительные знаки, в то время как на маке выводится изображение в нормальном виде

Comment: шрифт консоли менять пробовали?

Comment: @iiKuzmychov , нет, не пробовал. Не могли бы подсказать, каким образом?

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, так делал, выводит немного другие восклицательные знаки

Comment: попробуйте в гугле забить [шрифт консоли менять](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, помогло, но, конечно, хотел бы найти решение, при котором не надо будет людям менять шрифт в консоли вручную

Comment: может это именно на вашей машине такой шрифт в консоле был по умолчанию, а у остальных всё будет работать по дефолту, тут надо протестить

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, у меня дефолтный так же не работает

Comment: Стандартный шрифт Consolas не поддерживает эти символы юникода.